# Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010 to edit Visual Studio 2008 solutions without conversion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2010

I just downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 trial. It would be nice if I could try it out by doing some real work on some real projects, but I can't convert these projects to 2010 format, because then noone else could open them unless they also install VS2010.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: It's not a bug.  It's a feature ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this, unless you make a **separate copy of your project** a work on that.  It modifies a lot of files (solution, project, and depending: possibly your configs), that's just how it is at the moment.

[The Visual Studio team is discussing fixing this for the next release](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx), they refer to the concept as "round-tripping", making one set of solution/project files support multiple versions of visual studio.  Seeing as they have yet to do this though...that term may change :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this tool](http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/2010/02/tool-to-switch-project-files-between.html) to switch.

Comment: That looks interesting, though I'm nervous to try it given the content of the blog that @Nick Craver linked. I don't want to subtly screw up "real" projects. Hmm.

Comment: @blorgbeard: What's to screw up? You have version control, right? :) No guts, no glory.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert, it creates a backup. All that's really changed is the .sln file anyway, so if you take a copy of the 2008 .sln file other users can just use that to open it.

This is of course assuming you stick with .net3.5

**edit** - my bad, this is wrong.

Comment: The .sln and the .csproj files.

Comment: I tried that and not only did it modify all `csproj` files, it also botched my `app.config`s and WCF Service References. Caveat Emptor!

Comment: hmmm. What did it do to your app.config?
@Timores - ooh, didn't know it changed those too, cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on what type of projects you are creating.  I have experienced it working, but then I have only done it with 1 solution which contained a WPF and a Class library.

I wanted to do something similar, see here [in my project on codeplex](http://graphicalsvn.codeplex.com/)

Like I said not sure if this will work for you, but it did for me.

I was working on this at home and at work (not work related just for fun) I had a copy of 2010 beta at home and 2008 at work.

I initially started at work using vs2008, so when I went to open my project it brought up the upgrade wizard.

When I got to work the next day I chanced my arm and created a blank solution included the existing projects into this and saved the solution out (calling it something slightly different)

So when I was at work I was able to run the vs2008 solution file make some changed update those to codeplex and the when at home I could get the latest changes and open them using the 2010 solution file.